# SQL Calculate Days between two dates in one table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table `dbo.Trans` which contains an id called `bd_id`(varchar) and `transfer_date`(Datetime), also an identifier `member_id` pk is `trns_id` and is sequential

Duplicates of `bd_id` and `member_id` exist in the table.

```
transfer_date       |bd_id| member_id | trns_id
2008-01-01 00:00:00 | 432 | 111       | 1  
2008-01-03 00:00:00 | 123 | 111       | 2  
2008-01-08 00:00:00 | 128 | 111       | 3  
2008-02-04 00:00:00 | 123 | 432       | 4
.......
```

For each member_id, I want to get the amount of days between dates and for each `bd_id`

E.G., member `111` used `432` from `2008-01-01` until `2008-02-01` so return should be `2`
Then next would be `5`

I know the `DATEDIFF()` function exists but I am not sure how to get the difference when dates are in the same table.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server 2012 by any chance?

Comment: can you clarify each field in your sample data?  which one id member_id which one is bd_id and what is the last field?

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @bluefeet transfer_date, bd_id, member_id, trns_id

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
select T1.member_id,
       datediff(day, T1.transfer_date, T3.transfer_date) as DD
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply (select top 1 T2.transfer_date
               from YourTable as T2
               where T2.transfer_date > T1.transfer_date and
                     T2.member_id = T1.member_id
               order by T2.transfer_date) as T3
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77470)

Comment: I think you are missing an order by in the cross apply section

Answer (score 1):

You must select 1st and 2nd records that you want, then get their dates and get DATEDIFF of those two dates.

`DATEDIFF(date1, date2);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is getting the next member date.

Here is an example using a correlated subquery to get the next date:

```
select t.*, datediff(day, t.transfer_date, nextdate) as Days_Between
from (select t.*,
             (select min(transfer_date)
              from trans t2
              where t.bd_id = t2.bd_id and
                    t.member_id = t2.member_id and
                    t.transfer_date < t2.transfer_date
             ) as NextDate
      from trans t
     ) t
```

SQL Server 2012 has a function called lag() that makes this a bit easier to express.