# Retrieve records between a current date and previous date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a count of the # of rows resulting from a query which needs to have the below logic:

Assume the table includes 3 columns for now; ID, VALUE and INSERT DATE

---

Records inserted on

```
Current day-1
```

Minus
records inserted on

```
the latest business day prior to the (current day-1)
```

**To add more details:**
****I am looking for **'number of records' inserted between 2 dates** i.e. if 200 records were inserted between **Thursday and Friday** then when I run the query on **Monday my result should show me '200 records**'.

**Assumption:** Business days = Mon-Fri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Calculate Days between two dates in one table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007857/sql-calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-one-table)

Comment: Business days is going to be the key here, doing just days is easy in SQL but business days vary between companies. What version of sql server are you on?

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008. Yes, I need it to be business days i.e. Mon-Fri.

Comment: I think it would not be a duplicate of the other query because it retrieve the 'no. of days' but I am looking for 'number of records i.e. if 200 records were inserted between Thursday and Friday then when I run the query on Monday my result should show me '200 records'.

Answer (score 1):

USE **DATEADD** Function:

```
Select
*
FROM
TableName
WHERE CreatedDate Between CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE() AS Date) AND CAST( GETDATE() AS Date)
```

Comment: would this mean it will be hard coded? Sorry but the above query didn't work. Can you please advise based on the details I added on the question above?

Comment: can you please post your expected result and initial requirement, it better

Comment: Initial requirement: I am looking for 'number of records' inserted between 2 dates i.e. if 200 records were inserted between Thursday and Friday then when I run the query on Monday my result should show me '200 records'.

Assumption: Business days = Mon-Fri

Comment: Need initial and required table result

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Select * FROM TableName WHERE AddedDate Between DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Comment: This does not take business days into consideration.  What I am looking for is ''if 200 records were inserted between Thursday and Friday then when I run the query on Monday my result should show me '200 records''.